# Can I add text to page-source dynamically in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to add text dynamically to the page source in a particular view. I checked the IO streams, but couldn't find anything. Could you please provide some pointers.

Edit:

Thanks for the reply. I was trying to know how much time each part/component in a particular view takes to render and log it as part of the page-source. Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/pointers.png - sorry... couldn't help it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to modify the Document Object Model (DOM) of a page after Rails has rendered the view. If you edit your question to make it more specific then we can give more specific answers.